# list a number of data.frames for the output of an R function

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe

I was wondering how I could get my function below to output a list of `length(n.x)`, `data.frame`s, with each `data.frame` having `n.x[i]` rows in it.

`x` is a vector, and `n.x` determines the number of elements to be extracted from `x`, and `length(n.x)` determines the number of separate sets to become `data.frame`s.

For example, if `x = 1:5` and `n.x = c(2, 3)`, I want the first 2 elements of `x`(i.e., `1` and `2`) to become one `data.frame`, and and the last 3 elements of `x`(i.e., `3, 4, 5`) to become another `data.frame`. Then, I want these two `data.frame` to be outputted as a list.

**Update:** Some `x`s can have a `long= T`, and some `long= F`. After saving the call as an object (e.g., `a`), Can the user use `a$study1$long` to extract the `x`s for which `long = T` and `a$study1$short` to extract the `x`s for which `long = F`?

```
foo <- function(x, n.x, long) {

  a <- x 
  data.frame(a)
}

a <- foo(1:4, c(1, 2, 1), long = c(T, F, T, T) )

a$study1$short
a$study1$long
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the 'n.x' to create a grouping vector to `split` the data.frame into a `list` of `data.frame`s

```
foo <- function(x, n.x, long) {


    d1 <- data.frame(a = x, long)

    lst1 <- split(d1, list(rep(seq_along(n.x), n.x), long), drop = TRUE)
    names(lst1) <- paste0("Study", seq_along(lst1))
    lst1 <- lapply(lst1, `row.names<-`, NULL)
    lapply(lst1, function(x) setNames(x, c("a", c("short", "long")[x$long[1] +1])))

   } 



foo(1:4, c(1, 2, 1), c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE))
#$Study1
#  a short
#1 2 FALSE

#$Study2
#  a long
#1 1 TRUE

#$Study3
#  a long
#1 3 TRUE

#$Study4
#  a long
#1 4 TRUE
```

---

If we need to pass one more vector ('nn') and assign it as row names

```
foo <- function(x, n.x, long, nn, rowName = "character") {

        nn <- if(rowName == "character") {
                  nn
                 } else as.integer(factor(nn))


        d1 <- data.frame(a = x, long)
        row.names(d1) <- nn

        lst1 <- split(d1, list(rep(seq_along(n.x), n.x), long), drop = TRUE)
        names(lst1) <- paste0("Study", seq_along(lst1))
        #lst1 <- lapply(lst1, `row.names<-`, NULL)
        lapply(lst1, function(x) 
             setNames(x, c("a", c("short", "long")[x$long[1] +1])))

       } 

nn <- c("bigi, gigi, cigi", "fifi") 
nn1 <- unlist(strsplit(nn, ", "))
foo(1:4, c(1, 2, 1), c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE), nn1, rowName = "integer")
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193130/discussion-on-answer-by-akrun-list-a-number-of-data-frames-for-the-output-of-an).